# Linux: How do I upgrade ssh-keygen?

Tags: debian, ssh, upgrade, parameter, ssh-keygen

I want to make use of the updated version of ssh-keygen because that includes a hashing feature for fingerprints like so:

```
ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

But my current version doesn't recognize the -E parameter (part of the -l parameter).

(yes I already have a workaround to obtain my fingerprint hashes, but I'd like to upgrade this tool regardless).

How to upgrade? I'm running Debian 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Debian-style ways to upgrade `ssh-keygen`, since `openssh-client` isn’t available in the Debian 8 backports.

The first is to upgrade to Debian 9, since that has a new enough `openssh-client` package.

The second it to rebuild the Debian 9 package on Debian 8:

```
sudo apt install devscripts build-essential dh-exec dh-systemd libaudit-dev libedit-dev libgtk-3-dev libkrb5-dev libpam0g-dev libselinux1-dev libssl-dev libsystemd-dev libwrap0-dev
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh_7.4p1-10+deb9u1.dsc
cd openssh-7.4p1
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This will install a number of necessary build-dependencies (which you can uninstall afterwards), download the source code for the package from Debian 9, and build it. It will produce a number of packages in the parent directory which you can then install:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../openssh-client_7.4p1-10+deb9u1_*.deb
```

With this solution, it will be up to you to [keep track](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/openssh) of any updates to the package in Debian 9, and rebuild the package locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can't upgrade parts of a package (in this case a single file). You would need to upgrade the entire openssh-client package, and (at the moment) no new version of that exists in Debian backports, so you would need to look to third parties with all the risks that carries.

Answer (score 2):

To use a version of an open-source tool newer than that provided by your package manager, download the source code from the upstream source (in this case, [openssh.com](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html)), together with any required libraries (*e.g.*, [LibreSSL](https://www.libressl.org/)) and compile it on your own system.